# How to pass mock parameter in a method using Mockito & Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have class like the following:

```
public class Service {
  public String method1 (class1, class2){
  //do something
  return result          //Returns a string based on something 
 }
}
```

I want to test the class Service by calling the method 'method1' with mocked parameter (objects of Class1 & Class2). I don't have any idea, how to do this using Mockito.Can anyone help me with the initial push ?

Comment: It is not typical to mock method's arguments as they are mostly data oriented types. And mock is to deal with methods (i.e. functional types).

But if you really want it you may do: Foo mock = mock(Foo.class); http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Answer (score 1):

If class1 and class2 are simple values or POJOs, you should just not mock them:

```
public class ServiceTest {

    Service service;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        service = new Service();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
        // Prepare data
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        // maybe set some values
        ....

        // Test
        String result = this.service.method1(class1, class2);

        // asserts here...
    }
}
```

If class1 and class2 are more complicated classes, like services, it is strange to pass them as arguments... However I don't want to discuss your design, so I will just write an example of how you can do it:

```
public class ServiceTest {

    Service service;

    @Mock Class1 class1Mock;
    @Mock Class2 class2Mock;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        service = new Service();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
        // Mock each invocation of the "do something" section of the method
        when(class1Mock.someMethod).thenReturn(someValue1);
        when(class2Mock.someMethod).thenReturn(someValue2);
        ....

        // Test
        String result = this.service.method1(class1Mock, class2Mock);

        // asserts here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good example. However what when the test method has class1Mock, class2Mock and third parameter as an actual object like say an enum ?

`service.method1(class1Mock, class2Mock, someEnum.SOME_VALUE)`
I am facing an error for this scenario.

Comment: "An error"? XD
If I try to guess what you're facing without any information, I can say this:Normally with Mockito you have to use only mocks or only real instances. If you need to pass also an enum, you can use the eq(...) method

Comment: service.method1(class1Mock, class2Mock, eq(someEnum.SOME_VALUE))

Comment: But maybe this is not relevant for you

Comment: And to be precise, it's usually when you define the mocks or use verify